# Javascript Object Date Value

Tags: javascript, date, object

I have some images in a feature image slider. I need to make these programmable by date so that i don't have to go online to change these during the weekend or so on. I want to put a start date and an end date in the object. How do you use a date in an object (not as a string)?

```
var bannerOne = {dateStart:"08/12/2015", dateEnd:"08/13/2015", banner:"<li><a href=\"https://unsplash.it/200/300\"><img src=\"https://unsplash.it/500/300\" /></a></li>"};
var bannerTwo = {dateStart:"08/14/2015", dateEnd:"08/15/2015", banner:"<li><a href=\"https://unsplash.it/200/300\"><img src=\"https://unsplash.it/600/300\" /></a></li>"};
var bannerThree = {dateStart:"08/12/2015", dateEnd:"08/13/2015", banner:"<li><a href=\"https://unsplash.it/200/300\"><img src=\"https://unsplash.it/550/300\" /></a></li>"};
```

I want to compare the current date and see if the dates in the object include the current date and if so display that image.

I am still new to javascript.

Currently I use this code:

```
   <ul>   <script type="text/javascript">

  var banner = new Array();
banner[0] = "<li>First Statement</li>";
banner[1] = "<li>Second Statement</li>"; 
banner[2] = "<li>Third Statement</li>"; 
banner[3] = "<li>Fourth Statement</li>"; 
banner[4] = "<li>Fifth Statement</li>";


var d = new Date();
if (d.getDate() == 12)
{document.write(banner [0], banner [1], banner[2])}

/*Use this to program to be live during two dates !!!!LEAVE(-1)!!!!*/ else if (d.getMonth() == 8-1 && d.getDate() >= 10 && d.getDate() < 12) {document.write(banner [4], banner [1])}

else
{
document.write(banner [1], banner[2], banner [3], banner[4], banner [0]) }
</script>    </ul>
```

Comment: Just a note that if you format your dates like `yyyy-MM-dd`, you can sort them using `.sort()` (without conversion) and they'll be in date order. You can take the current date and use `.toISOString().substring(0, 10)` to get the same format. Not really an answer, but maybe something that will help down the road :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really look into using http://momentjs.com/  You can use isBetween, isBefore, isAfter...it's very flexible.

Comment: This may be the route to go. I will need to read the docs thoroughly as a quick glance does not help but i will work on it.

Comment: I got moment up and running for what i need it to do but i am having issues with another part of the script now. I am trying to make it easier for someone with even less JS knowledge than me to update 
The script below keeps giving me an unexpected identifier error do you see the issue?

'document.write('<li><a href="' banner1.link '"/><img src="' banner1.image '"/></a></li>')'

full code [link](http://codepen.io/mpmullally/pen/KpYZLG)

Comment: You should mark the question as answered and start a new one.  However, you need to add a + to concatenate the strings:  document.write('<li><a href="' + banner1.link + '"/><img src="' + banner1.image + '"/></a></li>')

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a date like this

```
var date = new Date("08/12/2015");
```

[More Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

To compare two dates you could do something like this:

```
var date1 = new Date("08/12/2015");
var date2 = new Date("07/12/2015");
if( date1.getTime() > date2.getTime()) {
     console.log(date1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var bannerOne = {dateStart:"08/12/2015", dateEnd:"08/13/2015", banner:"<li><a href=\"https://unsplash.it/200/300\"><img src=\"https://unsplash.it/500/300\" /></a></li>"};
            var bannerTwo = {dateStart:"08/14/2015", dateEnd:"08/15/2015", banner:"<li><a href=\"https://unsplash.it/200/300\"><img src=\"https://unsplash.it/600/300\" /></a></li>"};
            var bannerThree = {dateStart:"08/12/2015", dateEnd:"08/13/2015", banner:"<li><a href=\"https://unsplash.it/200/300\"><img src=\"https://unsplash.it/550/300\" /></a></li>"};

            //Todays Date
            var currentDate = new Date();

            //setting minutes, hours and seconds of current date to 0
            currentDate.setMinutes(0);
            currentDate.setHours(0);
            currentDate.setSeconds(0);

            var start=new Date (bannerOne.dateStart);
            var end=new Date (bannerOne.dateEnd);

            //comparing the startdate with current date by substraction, if the subtraction result is less than 0(negative value) then the date is still valid and similarly checking for end date.
            if (start - currentDate < 0 && end - currentDate > 0){
            document.write(bannerOne.banner);
            }
            //Banner Two
            start=new Date (bannerTwo.dateStart);
            end=new Date (bannerTwo.dateEnd);

            if (start - currentDate < 0 && end - currentDate > 0){
            document.write(bannerTwo.banner);
            }
            //Banner Three
            start=new Date (bannerThree.dateStart);
            end=new Date (bannerThree.dateEnd);

            if (start - currentDate < 0 && end - currentDate > 0){
            document.write(bannerThree.banner);
            }

        </script> 
    </body>
<html>
```